# building a webextension with parcel and web-ext, what is the correct content security policy

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions, parceljs, web-ext

Parcel supports bundling webextensions: https://v2.parceljs.org/recipes/web-extension/

The command to set up a build server and watch for changes is: `parcel src/manifest.json --host localhost --target webext-dev`. This will bundle a webextension into the `dist/` folder.

I'd like to run this extension with `web-ext run`. This is a tool from Mozilla which automatically loads a webextension into Firefox and reloads on changes. Running this in the `dist/` folder should make for a great pair with parcel.

But in practice the bundled webextension is not executing my content scripts.
This is because parcel is serving them from localhost. It needs the flag `--host localhost` for hot module replacement.
But the webextension then complains `"page's settings blocked loading of a resource at ws://localhost:1234/ (“connect-src”)."`

The parcel docs also demonstrate a build command: `parcel build src/manifest.json --target webext-prod`. And if I execute web-ext run from `dist/webext-prod` it works like a charm. A new run of the parcel build command automatically triggers a reload of the webextension. But this is not productive for development, since the parcel builds take too long. I'd like to use its development setup.

How can I correctly configure the content security policy of my webextension to allow content scripts that are loaded from localhost?

So far the entry in my `manifest.json` looks like this:

```
  "content_security_policy": "connect-src 'self' 'localhost:';",
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `'localhost:'` has a wrong syntax, no single-quotes and trailing colon ":" should be used. It's just specific hostname like domain name.
2. `localhost` source covers `http://localhost` and `https://localhost` (only http/https schemes), but [with standard ports](http://csplite.com/csp/test284/) only.
3. `'self'` token covers `ws://localhost` and `wss://localhost` host-source in CSP3-browsers only, and with standard ports only.

Since you do use non standard port number, try:

```
"content_security_policy": "connect-src 'self' ws://localhost:1234;"
```